# What's D lines for hydrogen like atom?

Tags: definition, spectroscopy

Could anyone tell me what's the definition of D lines for hydrogen like atoms?
(Not just those two lines for sodium.)

Comment: In sodium that is a 3p -> 3s transition. Now, what does that look like for hydrogen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines are from the solar spectrum, Fraunhofer's nomenclature.

> The Fraunhofer C, F, G', and h lines correspond to the alpha, beta, gamma and delta lines of the Balmer series of emission lines of the hydrogen atom. The Fraunhofer letters are now rarely used for those lines.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_lines

[image]

Comment: I think we have looked at the question in two different ways. In a true hydrogen-like atom there is no 3p->3s transition since there aren't other electrons to split the levels. Or that was my interpretation of what the analogue of a sodium D line was.

Comment: @JonCuster Indeed, there is no analogue, but I did not want to spoil your your question :)   And I thought that the OP maybe meant something like the x-ray nomenclature with K, L, M lines.